# Append New Data to Previous Query in Power Query

Tags: excel

I have a query in Power Query that is connected to a table within the same workbook. The entry table changes frequently. Is there a way to keep the previous results of the query and append the new data to it?

Answer (score 0):

This type of questions is more for [Super User](https://superuser.com/) rather than Stack Overflow, since it's not a programming question.
And as for your question: You need to make sure that the connection is frequently updated. In the Power Query tab click "show pane" and click on the source, and then simply hit "refresh". The data in the Power Query connection doesn't actively "listen" to the source to check for changes, the refresh is usually happening in the "load file" event (check your references) or when activated by the user.

UPDATE:
The purpose of Power Query is to separate the source data and the reporting layer. So your data is "somewhere", and the reporting layer that sits on top of it is being refreshed. How often? That's up to you to decide.

If you wish to create a snapshot in time for the data today, and the data tomorrow is going to be completely different, please post a different question stating: what's your data source? how often is it being refreshed? do you just wish to append or do you want to delete or update new data? that's a completely different question, which could be achieved with PQ, but we do need to know the details (data structure and what information you've got).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My goal is perserve the previous data and apend the new data to it.

Comment: @MuathAlqurashi: I've updated my answer based on your comments

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. It should be a comment

Comment: Hi,
The key word I got from your answer was snapshot.
I have found the answer in
https://www.thebiccountant.com/2016/02/09/how-to-create-a-load-history-or-load-log-in-power-query-or-power-bi/